Invert keyOf T type
Using typescript
how can i make "value" parameter in "formatValue" function to be the type of keyOf T?
export interface ICol<T extends Record<string, any>, K extends keyof T = keyof T> {
    accessor?: K;
    formatValue?: (value: T[K]) => JSX.Element | string | number;
}
const col: ICol<{ a: number; b: string; c: Date; }> = {
    accessor: 'a',
    formatValue: (value) => {
        return `Value is ${value}`;
    },
};

The tooltip must say value:number when accessor is "a" but value:string when accessor is "b". The current tooltip say: (parameter) value: string | number | date

I need value to be number in this case.
Thanks.

Why is formatValue an optional member function? That's not the most user-friendly API design...

cause if there is not formatValue.. i will just print the value as is!

• Please edit to include your tooltip info as plaintext.  • Is this approach what you're looking for? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplicate. If not, what am I missing?

wow! the solution works!.. i am trying to understand it! its amazing man! WOW! please write the answer to approve it.

I'm wondering if this problem can be solved just by using types, or if it's possible to use an interface instead. I know that using a type works, but I might be overcomplicating things by trying to make it work with an interface, and maybe it's not even possible.

No you cannot use interface here because we are effectively defining a union type. So it would be type MyUnion = 'foo' | 'bar' which you cannot define with interface.

You want ICol<{ a: number; b: string; c: Date; }> without a second generic type argument K to be equivalent to the union of ICol<{ a: number; b: string; c: Date; }, K> for each K in keyof T. That is, you want to distribute a union in K over the ICol<T> operation. There are two relatively straightforward ways to do that.

One is to use a distributive conditional type like this:
type ICol<T extends Record<string, any>, K extends keyof T = keyof T> =
  K extends unknown ? {
    accessor?: K;
    formatValue?: (value: T[K]) => JSX.Element | string | number;
  } : never

Because K is a generic type parameter, the conditional type K extends unknown ? ⋯ : never automatically distributes the ⋯ over unions in K. We're not really trying to check anything (K extends unknown is always true), just use distributive conditional type.  That results in:
type Z = ICol<{ a: number; b: string; c: Date; }>;
/* type Z = {
    accessor?: "a" | undefined;
    formatValue?: ((value: number) => JSX.Element | string | number) | undefined;
} | {
    accessor?: "b" | undefined;
    formatValue?: ((value: string) => JSX.Element | string | number) | undefined;
} | {
    accessor?: "c" | undefined;
    formatValue?: ((value: Date) => JSX.Element | string | number) | undefined;
} */

And then you get the behavior you expected where value is inferred as number:
const col: ICol<{ a: number; b: string; c: Date; }> = {
  accessor: 'a',
  formatValue: (value) => {
    return `Value is ${value}`;
  },
};


The other is to use a distributive object type as coined in microsoft/TypeScript#47109, where you make a mapped type over the union members of K and then immediately index into that mapped type with K:
type ICol<T extends Record<string, any>, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = { [P in K]: {
  accessor?: P;
  formatValue?: (value: T[P]) => JSX.Element | string | number;
} }[K]

Here we declare a type parameter P to iterate over the elements of K. This produces a mapped type with the same keys as T but whose properties are the object types we're looking for. When we index into this mapped type with K, we get the union of those object types.
So the same output happens:
type Z = ICol<{ a: number; b: string; c: Date; }>;
/* type Z = {
    accessor?: "a" | undefined;
    formatValue?: ((value: number) => JSX.Element | string | number) | undefined;
} | {
    accessor?: "b" | undefined;
    formatValue?: ((value: string) => JSX.Element | string | number) | undefined;
} | {
    accessor?: "c" | undefined;
    formatValue?: ((value: Date) => JSX.Element | string | number) | undefined;
} */


These types still let you pass in a type for K if you don't want to use the default keyof T, so you can get a more specific type if you want:
type X = ICol<{ a: number; b: string; c: Date; }, "a">;
/* type X = {
  accessor?: "a" | undefined;
  formatValue?: ((value: number) => JSX.Element | string | number) | undefined;
} */

If you don't need that ability you can rewrite ICol<T> to remove the second type parameter:
type ICol<T extends Record<string, any>> =
  keyof T extends infer K ? K extends keyof T ? {
    accessor?: K;
    formatValue?: (value: T[K]) => JSX.Element | string | number;
  } : never : never;

or
type ICol<T extends Record<string, any>> = { [P in keyof T]: {
  accessor?: P;
  formatValue?: (value: T[P]) => JSX.Element | string | number;
} }[keyof T]


Note that since ICol<T> needs to at least sometimes be a union type, you cannot make ICol<T> an interface. Interfaces can only represent single object types (or intersections of object types) with statically-known members.
Playground link to code

This is an excellent question and requires a bit of a trick to make it work. The final solution would look something like this...
export type $Values<T extends object> = T[keyof T];

export type ICol<T extends Record<string, any>> = $Values<{
  [K in keyof T]: {
    accessor?: K;
    formatValue?: (value: T[K]) => JSX.Element | string | number;
  }
}>

const colA: ICol<{ a: number; b: string; c: Date; }> = {
  accessor: 'a',
  formatValue: (value) => {
    return `Value is ${value.toFixed()}`; // value is a number
  },
};

const colB: ICol<{ a: number; b: string; c: Date; }> = {
  accessor: 'b',
  formatValue: (value) => {
    return `Value is ${value.charCodeAt(1)}`; // value is a string
  },
};

const colC: ICol<{ a: number; b: string; c: Date; }> = {
  accessor: 'c',
  formatValue: (value) => {
    return `Value is ${value.getDate()}`; // value is a Date
  },
};

TS Playground link
So what is this doing? The idea is that we want to get a resulting type that is a union of all the possible options, that would look something like this...
type FinalType =
  | {
      accessor?: 'a';
      formatValue?: ((value: number) => JSX.Element | string | number) | undefined;
    }
  | {
      accessor?: 'b';
      formatValue?: ((value: string) => JSX.Element | string | number) | undefined;
    }
  | {
      accessor?: 'c';
      formatValue?: ((value: Date) => JSX.Element | string | number) | undefined;
    };

To do this we loop over all the keys in the object T using the [K in keyof T] syntax. This will give us a type that looks like this...
type LoopedObjectTypes = {
  a: {
    accessor?: 'a';
    formatValue?: ((value: number) => JSX.Element | string | number) | undefined;
  };
  b: {
    accessor?: 'b';
    formatValue?: ((value: string) => JSX.Element | string | number) | undefined;
  };
  b: {
    accessor?: 'c';
    formatValue?: ((value: Date) => JSX.Element | string | number) | undefined;
  };
}

Then from there we just take the values across the object using the $Values helper type and we have our final type.

One thing I highly recommend when trying to understand complex type like this is to reference this utility-types repo which contains a bunch of helpful types to use in your code but also let's you see how the types are actually built.

